# I want to show a data whose values I have determined myself in text

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

```
 calculateButton.setOnClickListener {



          val panelC = binding.panelCount.text.toString()
          val panelS = binding.panelSize.text.toString()
          val landS = binding.landSlope.text.toString()
          val landSi = binding.landSize.text.toString()
          val cit = binding.city.text.toString()

          val sun = (1000).toInt()
          val air = (1.25).toFloat()
          val cel = (25).toInt()

          val verim = ((sun * air)/ cel).toString().toDouble()



          if (panelC.equals("") || panelS.equals("")|| landS.equals("")|| landSi.equals("")||cit.equals("")){
              Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"Alanları Doldurunuz.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
          }

          else{
              val action = SignUpCalculateFragmentDirections.actionSignUpCalculateFragmentToDataFragment()
              Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action)

          }
          val postMap = hashMapOf<String, Any>()
          postMap.put("Panel Sayisi",binding.panelCount.text.toString())
          postMap.put("Panel Boyutu",binding.panelSize.text.toString())
          postMap.put("Arazi Eğimi",binding.landSlope.text.toString())
          postMap.put("Arazi Boyutu",binding.landSize.text.toString())
          postMap.put("Şehir",binding.city.text.toString())
          postMap.put("date", Timestamp.now())
        postMap.put("verim",verim.toString().toDouble())


          firestore.collection("Posts").add(postMap).addOnFailureListener {

          }.addOnFailureListener {
              Toast.makeText(requireContext(),it.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
          }
```

There is a calculatePage Fragment Codes. On this page, I am trying to make a yield calculation based on the data I receive from the user. However, I need to add the values that are kept constant in the efficiency calculation, such as "sun", "cel", "air" that I defined in the code. I wrote a random operation there as an example. To see if I can write inside the text I'm trying to print without getting any errors. But the app crashed.

```
private fun getData(){
    firestore.collection("Posts").addSnapshotListener { value, error ->

        if (error!=null){
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(),error.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }else{
            if (value !=null){
                if (!value.isEmpty){
                    val documents = value.documents

                    for (document in documents){
                        val pc = document.get("Panel Sayisi") as String
                        val ps = document.get("Panel Boyutu") as String
                        val ls = document.get("Arazi Eğimi") as String
                        val lsi = document.get("Arazi Boyutu") as String
                        val c = document.get("Şehir") as String
                        val v = document.get("verim") as Double

                        val post = Post(pc,ps,ls,lsi,c,v)
                        postArrayList.add(post)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        db.collection("Posts").orderBy("date",Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(1)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                val result : StringBuffer = StringBuffer()
                if (it.isSuccessful){
                    for (document in it.result){
                        result.append(document.data.getValue("verim"))
                    }

                    verimText.setText(result)
                }
            }
```

On this page, I added the values I defined in my class named 'post' to the postList and added them to Firestore.

```
data class Post(val pc: String, val ps: String, val ls: String, val lsi: String, val c: String, val v : Double)
@ServerTimestamp
var date: Date? = null
```

This is my post class

The error is like this: java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null
type kotlin.Double

As I explained at the beginning of my question, what I am trying to do is using both the data such as "panelCount", "panelSize" that I get from the user and the "sun", "cel", "air" values that are defined as constants, using the "verimText.setText(result)" in the DataFragment page. I need to show this calculation to the user.

[image]

The user enters values such as 'Panel Sayisi', 'Panel Boyutu' that should be used while calculating on the calculation page. I need to show this to the user in verimText using both this data and the 'cel', 'sun', 'air' constants that I wrote in the first code.

PS: verim: 20000 value is the result of hypothetical values that I wrote in the first code. In this part, I need to make a calculation using the other data entered by the user and these constant values and show it in the verimText.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data you want to use.

Comment: I added the image. I think it's more descriptive

Comment: Are there any documents inside "Posts" collection that doesn't contain the `verim` field?

Comment: No there isn't.

Comment: If you try this, `if(document.getLong("verim") != null) {val v = document.getLong("verim")}`, does it work?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Field 'verim' is not a java.lang.Number 
now there is a like this error.

Comment: As I see verim is a number and not a Double, right?

Comment: It has the potential to be a double. Because the 'air' variable has the value 1.25. But all other values are integers

Comment: Can you change this line of code `val v = document.get("verim") as Double` to `val v = document.get("verim") as? Double` and check if that resolves the error?